# Cable Shielding for Non-Isolated Differential Signals

Tags: rf, cables, differential

If I am transferring data from one device to another using a non-isolated differential signaling standard like LVDS or RS-422 through a cable, and each device has its own single-point ground, should I ground the shielding at one side only, or at both sides? And if it should only be grounded at one side, does it matter which side?

Here's what I think. Grounding on both sides could create a ground loop, but it's unlikely that most of the return current for any other high-speed signals inside one of the devices will flow along that shield because it will not be the path of least impedance. Going through the chassis of one device, along the shield to the other device, and then back seems like an unlikely return path for a high speed signal due to the very large loop inductance.

If one of the devices powers the other device, it's possible the return current for the power will go through the shield, especially if there is no specific power return wires in the cable or another cable connecting the devices. This could be dangerous if it's really high current which seems like an argument for bonding the shielding to ground on only one side. This also reduces the probability of inducing power supply noise on the LVDS signals, although if the wires are twisted and controlled impedance, most of that noise would be common-mode.

One argument I've heard against bonding the shielding to ground on only one side is that doing so essentially turns the cable shielding into an antenna that can radiate rf signals it picks up into the wires in the cable. My thought is that although it may be an antenna, the skin depth of the shielding will determine how much of the signal radiates back into the cable, and even if some of it does, the noise will still be common mode. Most of the rf signals picked up will stay on the outside of the shielding

This leads me to the following conclusions:

1. If one device powers the other, and there are high currents involved, ground the shielding at one end only, and provide return current paths between them that do not include the chassis of either device.
2. Otherwise, I don't see a good argument against either method. If the devices are electrically isolated from each other except for the differential signals, meaning the shielding is only bonded to ground on one side and they have separate power sources, would noise in the ground of one system affect the other through the differential signals? I think it might since the differential signals in this case are not truly isolated (like Ethernet which uses a transformer), but if it doesn't, that may be an argument for bonding the shielding to ground on one side instead of both.

Any further insight on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> *Any further insight on this would be helpful.*

As you say, high frequency signals (from say `DATA B`) will not to want to occupy the shield or return conductor of `DATA A` so, you can largely discount that as a possibility.

You are also concerned about the unterminated shield being an antenna and, that if you ground both ends of that shield, you might attract unwanted power currents through the shield so, another possibility is that you terminate one end with a low value capacitor like 10 pF (or 100 pF) to prevent the cable turning into an antenna and simultaneously prevent it carrying significant high currents from power supply returns.

You could also choose to fit ferrite rings on the data cables individually as these will alleviate the problem of passing noise from one ground/chassis to another.

Generally, if you decide to ground one end of a shield and not the other, you would favour grounding the receiver end because, it is the receiver that has to deal with interference from other cables and, it's best if these are dumped into ground/chassis at the receiver.

Comment: One problem with using a low value cap on one end is that I do not see how that would work with a well designed cable shield, where the shields are connected to the metal backshells of the connectors on both ends, which are then tied to chassis through the connector housing itself .

Comment: @SteveSh there are ways of doing this but, it's always best if they are planned for beforehand. I've seen methods that break the shield and apply a capacitive coupler to bridge it as high frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you describe does not say if the two devices have a ground connection between them or not. If yes, then connect shield on one end only to avoid ground loops. If devices are unreferenced or floating in regard to each other (say both are battery operated handheld devices), the shield must be connected on both ends to create a single ground connection between them. When only one end connects to shield, it is usually the transmitter side.

1. If both devices already share a common ground potential reference, such as share a same power supply, or they are earthed via electrical wiring or have their grounds connected to same metallic chassis etc, it is common to connect cable shield directly to ground on one device (A) only to avoid ground loops, so that DC return currents don't have a return route via the shield, if for example supply return wire gets disconnected. On the other device (B), the shield can be left floating, or to improve EMI, the high frequency return path can be arranged by connecting the shield via a capacitor to the ground of other device (B).
2. If devices are isolated from each other, it means they are floating in respect to each other, so there is no common ground reference. For example take two USB chargers. They both have 5V output but they are isolated so no DC path between the power supplies. Yet the grounds of the power supplies may have a hundred volts AC at mains frequency between them due to capacitive coupling, or tens of volts of high frequency square wavy switching due to capacitive coupling of the switch mode power supply. RS-422 only allows a 7V difference between device grounds, so clearly data transmission cannot work and RS-422 chips can be damaged unless the grounds of two devices are connected together, to make their grounds to be at the same potential, so there is 0V between them.

What my answer #2 is trying to say is that for some reason people have a misconception that RS-422 and RS-485 only needs the two data wires to work, but for example the RS-485 standard mandates that for proper operation there must be a signal return path between device grounds.

It is also said in literature, that the shield should not be used as a conductor for carrying any currents, and thus if there is a need to connect device grounds together, the cable should have an extra wire for grounding, and it is best to connect the shield on one end only.

Answer (score 1):

"One argument I've heard against bonding the shielding to ground on only one side is that doing so essentially turns the cable shielding into an antenna that can radiate rf signals it picks up into the wires in the cable. My thought is that although it may be an antenna, the skin depth of the shielding will determine how much of the signal radiates back into the cable, and even if some of it does, the noise will still be common mode. Most of the rf signals picked up will stay on the outside of the shielding"

This is only partly correct.  The problem with a shield grounded on one end is that it can radiate any noise that makes its way onto the cable shield from the system - an antenna. This can cause you to fail a radiated emissions (RE) requirement.  Since antennas are reciprocal, it's also true that such a shield (grounded on one end only) can pick up noise and bring it back into the system, which could cause your system to fail it's radiated susceptibility (RS) requirement.

High speed systems almost always have their shields grounded on both ends.

A system I worked on almost 50 years ago used triple shielded cables for RS-422 interfaces.  One shield was grounded on one end, and the other two were grounded on both ends.  We needed the attenuation provided by the 3 shields to meet our shielding requirement, greater than 120 dB IIRC.